# display images in image slider sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

In my SharePoint home page I'm using a image slider. So I've saved some images in this path `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES\images`. So in this folder there are some images. But in the browser I'm only getting 2 images. Remaining images are not displaying. This means they are appearing as some crashed image. But in the images folder I'm able to see all the images. But in the browser only 2 images(new and mutual) are displaying, images `3.jpg` and `1.jpg` are not displaying.

```
<div id="slideshow"><div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8 can" >
                <div id="featured-slider">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="../../images/new.jpg" class="img-responsive"  alt=""/>                        </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="../../images/mutual.jpg" class="img-responsive"  alt=""/>                        </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="../../images/3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>                        </a>
                        <a href="#">
                        <img src="../../images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>                        </a>                    </div>
          </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a lot of space between the img tag and the closing `</a>` tag. Try to remove all white space and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: am done as u said. still some images r not displaying, some are displaying

Comment: Can you explain why you store the images for a slider in the 14 hive on the server? Why don't you put them into an image or asset library in the site collection where content belongs?